# SQL How to find max date grouped by month where a value appears

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2016

I have a table that contains a date column, a code column, and an count column. Each day the table is updated and if there is something in the code column to capture, it is recorded. However, not every code has something to record each day, so I would like to see the latest record for each code in each month. I am wondering if there is an aggregate function or something else that I can do to achieve this. Right now I have this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(date) as 'date'
    ,CONCAT(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date), 0)) AS VARCHAR(10)), ' ', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, date)), 2)) AS 'month'
    ,code
    ,count
FROM counttable
WHERE 
    area = 'total'
    AND type = 'cost' 
GROUP BY 
    CONCAT(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, date), 0)) AS VARCHAR(10)), ' ', RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2), DATEPART(MONTH, date)), 2)) 
    ,code
    ,count
ORDER BY 1, 3
```

This isn't working I think because there can be different counts for the same code throughout the month. I can't do the MAX() count either as the count can down as well as up throughout the month. How can I go about getting the last value grouped by month or any other date grouping larger than a day.

Example of what I am trying to get:

```
|date       | month    | code | count
|01/27/2022 |  2022 01 |  PT  |   7
|01/31/2022 |  2022 01 |  CR  |   15
|02/28/2022 |  2022 02 |  PT  |   9
|02/28/2022 |  2022 02 |  CR  |   19
```

So the last date for each code may not be the last day of the month, as seen in the first row. So if that is the case I want to get that count as that is the last day the code actually appears in the month.

Comment: Can you throw together a few sample rows of data you are querying against and an example of your desired output based on those sample rows? nothing too complicated. It is tough to decipher what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "category"? You seem to have the following columns: `code`, `type`, `area`, `count`, `date`.

Comment: The category should be ```code```. Edited. The ```area``` and ```type``` are just for filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT
 date
 , month
 , code
 , count
FROM
(
SELECT 
    date
    , FORMAT(date, 'yyyy MM') 'month'
    , code
    , count
    , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY code, FORMAT(date, 'yyyy MM') ORDER BY date DESC) rn
FROM counttable
WHERE 
    area = 'total'
    AND type = 'cost'
)
WHERE rn = 1 
ORDER BY 1, 3
```

The inner query uses `row_number` to mark the row with the most recent `date` (because of `ORDER BY date DESC`) for each `code` and `month` (because of the `PARTITION BY`) as 1. The outer query grabs the rows marked `rn`=1 (and removes the `rn` column).

So for each `code` and `month` you end up with the maximum `date` and the `count` associated with that maximum date.

Although it's separate from your question, I changed your month calculation to `FORMAT(date, 'yyyy MM')`. This seems much cleaner to me and, unless I'm misunderstanding something about your existing code, it's equivalent. The above query would work with your existing `month` calculation if there's a reason to prefer that.

Comment: No, there is no good reason I had the months calculated that way. That part was just from past versions trying to group things by weeks or by other date groupings. As for your solution, it seems to be close, but I am seeing that it is grabbing the last value for each code grouped by year instead of by month. I was hoping to get the last value within in each month if that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand why that would be. `PARTITION BY code, FORMAT(date, 'yyyy MM')` should ensure the numbering starts over for each month. Can you run the inner query and find where the numbering is wrong? Can you ensure `FORMAT(date, 'yyyy MM')` is distinct per month (I did test on SQL Server 2016)?

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault. I had ```'yyyy mm'``` in the ```rn``` section. Fixed it so it is now ```'yyyy MM'``` and that seems to have worked!